# В предложении " В целях улучшения работы педагогического коллектива по окончанию третьей четверти приказываю:..." По окончаниЮ или по окончаниИ?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно написать: работа по окончанию четверти или по окончании четверти?

Comment: по окончании - https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/slovar-trudnostey/zavershenie

Comment: по окончании - когда? а по окончанию - по чему? Например: Все это — мораль монастырская, и, судя по окончанию этой поэмы, нельзя не сказать...(Успенский)  ~ судя по концу поэмы.

Answer (score 0):

Объяснения см. на примере предлога "по прошествии":

> По прошествии — данное устойчивое выражение употребляется в качестве
> предлога. В подобных оборотах с предлогом «по» существительное
> употребляется в форме предложного падежа (по истечении, по
> завершении). Соответственно, в форме предложного падежа
> существительное «прошествие» пишется с окончанием на «и» — по
> прошествии. Написание всего предлога зафиксировано в орфографических
> словарях.

*...работа **по окончании** четверти.*